# Amount of distributed generation installed capacity?

Tags: renewables, electricity-generation

Since there are no data available (I didn't find anything regarding that :( ) I was trying to estimate the amount of distributed generation installed in the European electric grid. To do so, I thought that a good estimate could be to assume that 90% of the installed renewable energy generation is connected to the distribution grid (and the installed RES generation is available) because the main part of this type of generation is usually connected to the distribution grid. But I have some doubts:

1. Are there non-renewable energy sources connected to the distribution grid?
2. Which is a good estimate of the percentage of RES connected to the distribution grid? I think for example that all concentrated solar energy plants and geothermal power plants are connected to the high voltage grid due to the very huge size of these plants, but what about the other types (BIOMASS, HYDRO, and WIND)? For PV I think that 99% of generation is connected to distribution grid for example. Basically I have no experience, so I don't know the most common size of these types of generation.

Comment: Should your point #1 read something more like "Are there non-renewable *distributed* energy sources..."? Because there certainly are non-renewable sources connected to the grid ...

Comment: @brhans I said ''connected to the DISTRIBUTION grid'' so it is the same of your observation

Comment: Ok nevermind - your differentiation of "high voltage grid" vs "distribution grid" went way over my electronics head...

Comment: @brhans ahahaha don't worry ;)

Comment: EuroStat does not appear to differentiate the two using any keywords I tried. That's very annoying. But it is the obvious place to look.